# Pidgin can't connect to Facebook chat

Tags: pidgin, facebook, xmpp

After some time, I tried to connect to my Facebook account with Pidgin. Same account setting as last time (Feb 2014). But now, the connection fails.

The error is always the same "connection closed", here is last server reply from the logfile:

```
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(232): <iq from='chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cde0' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/><error code='501' type='cancel'><feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(234): <iq from='proxy.eu.jabber.org' id='purple74e1cde1' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/><error code='501' type='cancel'><feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
```

I don't fully understand where the problem is - what is not implemented and how to fix it - Can I change (disable) something in the settings or some plugins or what? Here is the complete log:

```
(13:20:10) account: Connecting to account my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/.
(13:20:10) perl: ret_val = (nil)
(13:20:10) connection: Connecting. gc = 0x7f2bcac79de0
(13:20:10) dnssrv: querying SRV record for chat.facebook.com: _xmpp-client._tcp.chat.facebook.com
(13:20:10) dnssrv: found 1 SRV entries
(13:20:10) dnsquery: Performing DNS lookup for chat.facebook.com
(13:20:10) dns: Wait for DNS child 2556 failed: Žádný potomek neexistuje
(13:20:10) dns: Created new DNS child 3277, there are now 1 children.
(13:20:10) dns: Successfully sent DNS request to child 3277
(13:20:10) dns: Got response for 'chat.facebook.com'
(13:20:10) dnsquery: IP resolved for chat.facebook.com
(13:20:10) proxy: Attempting connection to 2a03:2880:21:f05:face:b00c:0:133
(13:20:10) proxy: Connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222 with no proxy
(13:20:10) proxy: Connection in progress
(13:20:10) proxy: Connecting to chat.facebook.com:5222.
(13:20:10) proxy: Connected to chat.facebook.com:5222.
(13:20:10) jabber: Sending (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <?xml version='1.0' ?>
(13:20:10) jabber: Sending (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <stream:stream to='chat.facebook.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(13:20:10) jabber: Recv (389): <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream from='chat.facebook.com' id='1' version='1.0' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
(13:20:10) jabber: Sending (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(13:20:11) jabber: Recv (50): <proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
(13:20:11) gnutls: Starting handshake with chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) gnutls: Handshake complete
(13:20:11) gnutls/x509: Key print: 21:f1:6b:d6:61:95:d5:b4:3a:06:b4:e9:a0:50:7e:15:30:56:2e:d3
(13:20:11) gnutls/x509: Key print: 42:85:78:55:fb:0e:a4:3f:54:c9:91:1e:30:e7:79:1d:8c:e8:27:05
(13:20:11) gnutls: Peer provided 2 certs
(13:20:11) gnutls: Lvl 0 SHA1 fingerprint: 21:f1:6b:d6:61:95:d5:b4:3a:06:b4:e9:a0:50:7e:15:30:56:2e:d3
(13:20:11) gnutls: Serial: 0e:d4:76:ae:d4:8f:08:69:d3:b7:f3:1a:16:fc:76:3d
(13:20:11) gnutls: Cert DN: C=US,ST=CA,L=Menlo Park,O=Facebook\, Inc.,CN=chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) gnutls: Cert Issuer DN: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
(13:20:11) gnutls: Lvl 1 SHA1 fingerprint: 42:85:78:55:fb:0e:a4:3f:54:c9:91:1e:30:e7:79:1d:8c:e8:27:05
(13:20:11) gnutls: Serial: 0a:5f:11:4d:03:5b:17:91:17:d2:ef:d4:03:8c:3f:3b
(13:20:11) gnutls: Cert DN: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
(13:20:11) gnutls: Cert Issuer DN: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
(13:20:11) certificate/x509/tls_cached: Starting verify for chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) certificate/x509/tls_cached: Checking for cached cert...
(13:20:11) certificate/x509/tls_cached: ...Found cached cert
(13:20:11) gnutls: Attempting to load X.509 certificate from /home/cigi/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers/chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) certificate/x509/tls_cached: Peer cert matched cached
(13:20:11) util: Writing file /home/cigi/.purple/certificates/x509/tls_peers/chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) certificate: Successfully verified certificate for chat.facebook.com
(13:20:11) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <stream:stream to='chat.facebook.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(13:20:11) jabber: Recv (ssl)(338): <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream from='chat.facebook.com' id='1' version='1.0' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
(13:20:11) sasl: Mechs found: X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM PLAIN
(13:20:11) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN' xmlns:ga='http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth' ga:client-uses-full-bind-result='true'>password removed</auth>
(13:20:12) jabber: Recv (ssl)(51): <success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/>
(13:20:12) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <stream:stream to='chat.facebook.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
(13:20:12) jabber: Recv (ssl)(304): <?xml version='1.0' ?><stream:stream from='chat.facebook.com' id='1' version='1.0' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></stream:features>
(13:20:12) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com): <iq type='set' id='purple74e1cdda'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'/></iq>
(13:20:12) jabber: Recv (ssl)(177): <iq from='my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cdda' type='result'><bind xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind'><jid>my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx</jid></bind></iq>
(13:20:12) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='set' id='purple74e1cddb'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(131): <iq from='my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cddb' type='result'><session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cddc' to='chat.facebook.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cddd' to='chat.facebook.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(232): <iq from='chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cddc' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/><error code='501' type='cancel'><feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(312): <iq from='chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cddd' type='result'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><identity category='server' type='Facebook XMPP'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/><feature var='vcard-temp'/></query></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cdde'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cddf'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cde0' to='chat.facebook.com'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Sending (ssl) (my-secret-name@chat.facebook.com/xxxxxxxx): <iq type='get' id='purple74e1cde1' to='proxy.eu.jabber.org'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(232): <iq from='chat.facebook.com' id='purple74e1cde0' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/><error code='501' type='cancel'><feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Recv (ssl)(234): <iq from='proxy.eu.jabber.org' id='purple74e1cde1' type='error'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/><error code='501' type='cancel'><feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
(13:20:13) jabber: Discovered bytestream proxy server: jid='proxy.eu.jabber.org' host='' port='0' zeroconf=''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook chat XMPP servers stopped working for jabber clients like pidgin and empathy.

You can find answer in below link :

[Facebook Chat Will Stop Working in Ubuntu This Week](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working)

Comment: Oh, missed that. Their bad:) Thanks for pointing that out.